# How can I see chat messages starred by others?

Tags: support, chat-stars

I just [earned the outspoken badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/998/outspoken?userid=1356107) out of the blue. I rarely use chat, so I'm really surprised to find I said enough interesting things for people to star apparently.

But I wouldn't know where or what I said in what room would be worthy of being starred.

Is there a SEDE query or something that can provide me insight exactly what blurb of mine was starred?

For clarification:

I **don't** need to see *who* starred; I need to see **what text** was starred. I want to know what I said that was starred.

Comment: SEDE won't work; it does not contain any chat data at all.

Comment: @Glorfindel so that leaves an "or something" option, or.. "or nothing" which would be sad.

Comment: I fear it's "or nothing unless you use a yet to be developed userscript"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can.

Sort of.  As long as you know what chat rooms you've used.

Go to that chatroom and look to the left above the star gallery and you'll see a "show all xxx" link:

[image]

Hit the link

Then hit the "posted by me" link:

[image]

This will show you all of the chat messages posted by you in this room that have been starred by others (and how many times each has been starred).

This should give you the droid your're looking for.

Comment: So, this means having to dig through my memory and doing manual labor to check up. Okay, so be it :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you know which room/s you might have been in, you can look at the star histories. For example, [here's the stars list](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta/?tab=stars) for the Tavern on the Meta. On that page, you can sort by either items you've starred or things you've posted that were starred:

[image: Option to see posts starred by self "starred by me" circled.]

You get to this page by clicking on the "show all *n*" in the right sidebar above the stars list.

[image: Show all stars link in chat room]

So, if you really want to know, that's probably the easiest way to find it - assuming you know what rooms you've been in.

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead and made a little script based upon the information provided by [Snow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/351483/snow) and [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija).

Just paste this in the console when looking at your messages.
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/11/php/?tab=stars&filter=mymessages

Before you run it modify start room id and end room id to it encompasses the rooms you want, or modify the loop that it loops through an array of relevant room ids.

My output

[image]

```
+function() {
    var startRoomId = 1;
    var endRoomId = 20;
    var textList = [];
    var TextObj = function(str, stars, room) {
            this.room = room;
            this.text = str;
            this.stars = stars;
    }
    for(var c=startRoomId; c < endRoomId; c++) {

        $.ajax({
              url: 'https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/'+c+'/php/?tab=stars&filter=mymessages', 
              success: function(res) {
                var $response = $(res);
                var texts = $response.find('.monologue .messages .message');

                var room = $response.find('#content .subheader h1').text().trim();
                texts.each(function(index, domElement) {
                    var $el = $(domElement);
                    var number = parseInt($el.find('.stars.vote-count-container .times').text());

                    $el.find('.stars.vote-count-container .times').text('');
                    var obj = new TextObj($el.text().trim(), isNaN(number)?1:number, room);
                    if(obj.text.length > 0) { 
                        textList.push(obj);
                    }
            });

          },
        });
    }
    console.log(textList); 
}()
```